# Want to call a activity when finger hold on touch screen in android

Tags: android, android-activity, touch, screen

i want to call other activity when a user hold on touch screen.suitable answer appreciable
.

Comment: i think use long press and call new activity

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: use parent layout long press event to call new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.content);
    v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
        }
    });
```

(Obviosly replace variable names with your own)